# What is the purpose of the designer files in Visual Studio 2008 Web application projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-applications

There is a conversion process that is needed when migrating Visual Studio 2005 web site to Visual Studio 2008 web application projects.

It looks like VS2008 is creating a .designer. file for every aspx when you right click on a file or the project itself in Solution Explorer and select 'Convert to Web Application.'

What is the purpose of these designer files?  And these won't exist on a release build of the web application, they are just intermediate files used during development, hopefully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They hold all the form designer stuff that used to go in the #Region " Web Form Designer Generated Code " section of the code.  instead of putting it in the .aspx.vb file where people might edit it (mistakenly or not), it's been moved to a separate file, so that you don't have ever look at it.

Answer (score 1):

What kibbee said.

For the part of your question about existing on a release build, it depends on what kind of web site you have.  If you have a pre-compiled web site, then *none* of code files (.vb, .cs, etc) need to be deployed the server.  They are compiled into .dlls (assemblies) and deployed that way along with the .as*x files.